# Speech recognition engine is not installed on PosReady7

Tags: error-handling, speech-recognition, speech, windows-7-embedded

I've been trying to use an application that I made on the PosReady7 that uses `System.Speech`, but I'm receiving an error message informing:

> No recognizer of the required ID found

I already tried to install  the following .exe files, but any of them has worked:

```
 Speech SDK 5.1
 Microsoft Speech Platform - Runtime (Version 11)
 Microsoft Speech Platform - Runtime Languages (Version 11)
```

Even though I had installed all of this features, I'm still receiving the same error, "No recognizer of the required ID found".

When I try to open the Configuration Speech Recognition Tab, I also receive the following error message:

> The requested task cannot be carried out because the necessary engine
>   could not be created. Please select a different engine and/or a
>   different audio device.

Please, can anyone help me how to solve these problems ?